# Using Meteor with Iron:Router, js to open a route with a guaranteed refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

We have js code for Iron:Router to go to a new route:

```
Router.go('/');
```

We have code to reload and page:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

What is the code to accomplish both of these at once (so that the user goes to the new route and the page is guaranteed to reload)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your reloading statements into the `template` if there's only one template rendering in the route.

```
Template.name.onRendered(function(){
 // reloading code goes here.
});
```

Or you can use `onAfterAction` hook of Iron router to accomplish the reload.

http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Wouldn't either one of these approaches result in the page reloading indefinitely (each time it renders, it reloads)?

Comment: yes, each time it'll reload. I'm really interested to what is the reason behind reloading a page after when it's loaded for once. and if the answer helps you , you may mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear.  I *don't* want it to keep reloading indefinitely.  I just want it to go to the route and reload it once.  Thanks again.

Comment: try using `session` and then use the reload function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer, just like plain HTML5:

```
window.location.href = "/";
```

This will reload the entire app (which is what was desired in this case).